# Data constructor has different semantics when populating data across iOS versions

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

Here is the poc piece of code I had:

```
let text = "Hello, World"
let data = text.data(using: .utf8)! as CFData
    
let newData = Data(data as NSData)
print(newData.base64EncodedString())
return true
```

When I run this in a device running iOS 13 or 14, I get the following output:

```
SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk
```

which is the correct base64 for "Hello, World". However, when I run the exact same code in iOS 12, I get the following:

```
SAAAAAAAAAAMAAAA
```

which is quite meaningless in text (utf-8) format, but the hex for this is:

```
48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00
```

So I'm not sure what is happening here, and even if it was just filling in zeroes, why is it just not zeroes all the way through? While I get that what I'm doing is wrong, and the following works perfect on all versions:

```
print((data as Data).base64EncodedString())
```

I'm just curious as to why is it acting differently on the versions. The documentation does not seem to mention any particular behavioral caveat in an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please stop dealing with `CFData` and `NSData`

In Swift the recommended API to convert a `String` to `Data` is

```
let text = "Hello, World"
let data = Data(text.utf8)

print(data.base64EncodedString())
```

It works reliably in all versions and it avoids the optional.

The problem is the unnecessary `CF - NS` bridging. It seems that a zero-terminator is inserted after the `H` somewhere.